# How can I get the max of an arbitrary property from a list in Scala?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Foo(Prop1:Int, Prop2:Int, Prop3:Int)
{
 ..
}
```

And I wanted to create a function that gets the max of some arbitrary property from a list of `Foo`s.

Like this:

```
def getMax(Foos:List[Foo], Property:??) = Foos.map(_.Property).sort(_ > _).head
```

If I called `getMax(myFooList, Prop1)`, it would return the value of the highest `Prop1` from this list of `Foo`s.

My question is, how can I make this work? I guess I could create some kind of enum (the scala equivalent) for the `Property` and do a `match` and then run the `map` on the appropriate property, but that seems like a lot of work - I'd have to extend my enum and the function each time `Foo` is refactored.

Also, not as important, but is there a better way to grab the max value of a list then what I did?

Comment: "Also, not as important, but is there a better way to grab the max value of a list then what I did?"  Yes, just extract the list of properties you want and then use "max" on it, see below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply pass another function into getMax to instruct it how to map each Foo:

```
case class Foo(p1:Int, p2:Int)

def getMax(foos:List[Foo], mapper:Foo=>Int):Int = foos.map(mapper).foldLeft(Math.MIN_INT)((i,m)=>m.max(i))

val fooList = List(Foo(1,2),Foo(2,2),Foo(3,2),Foo(4,2))

getMax(fooList,_.p1)
//-->  4
```

Comment: Note that for an empty list this will return Math.MIN_INT

Comment: By the way: An even better and shorter way to get the min is to use reduceLeft.

Comment: The method `reduceLeft` won't work on empty lists, so it should be used with care.

Answer (score 16):

You should use standard [`maxBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) method:

```
List(("a", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 4)).maxBy(_._2)
=> (String, Int) = (c,4)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do this so simply using existing functionality that writing your own getMax is probably unnecessary:

```
scala> val fooList = List(Foo(1,2),Foo(2,2),Foo(3,2),Foo(4,2))
fooList: List[Foo] = List(Foo(1,2), Foo(2,2), Foo(3,2), Foo(4,2))

scala> fooList.map(_.p2).max
res12: Int = 2

scala> fooList.map(_.p1).max
res13: Int = 4
```

If you wanted to specify the property 'getter' elsewhere you could do it like this:

```
scala> def p1 = (f: Foo) => f.p1
p1: Foo => Int

scala> def p2 = (f: Foo) => f.p2
p2: Foo => Int

scala> fooList.map(p1).max
res14: Int = 4

scala> fooList.map(p2).max
res15: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is by passing to the `getMax()` method a function that knows how to extract the required property out of your `Foo`, i.e. something of type `Foo => Int`.

The way I would do it therefore is as follows:

```
scala> case class Foo(p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> def getMax(foos: List[Foo], prop: Foo => Int) = foos.map(prop).sort(_ > _).head
getMax: (List[Foo],(Foo) => Int)Int

scala> val lst = List(Foo(1,2,3), Foo(2,3,4), Foo(3,4,5))
lst: List[Foo] = List(Foo(1,2,3), Foo(2,3,4), Foo(3,4,5))

scala> getMax(lst, _.p1)
res0: Int = 3

scala> getMax(lst, _.p2)
res1: Int = 4

scala> getMax(lst, _.p3)
res2: Int = 5
```

`-- Flaviu Cipcigan`

Answer (score 1):

You can use objects inheriting from `Product`. It will be simpler and more type safe if you know arity in advance:

```
def getMax(foos: List[Product2[Int,Int]], f: Product2[Int,Int] => Int) = foos.map{f} ....
```

Then, you are free to feed `getMax` with anything like `Tuple`, e.g.

```
class Foo(val prop1: Int, val prop2: Int) extends Tuple2[Int, Int](prop1, prop2)
// this will duplicate values in an object actually.

getMax((new Foo(1,2)), _._2)
```

or inherit right from `Product`:

```
class Bar(val prop1: Int, val prop2: Int) extends Product2[Int, Int] {
  def _1 = prop1
  def _2 = prop2
}
val b = new Bar(2, 3)
getMax(List(b), _._2)
```

or simply use Scala's tuples:

```
getMax( (1,10) :: Nil, _._2)
getMax( List(1 -> 10), _._2)
// these are the same
```

Everything will become more complicated in case you do not know arity beforehand, because generic `Product` will let you retrieve elements as `Any` only (See `Product.productElement(n: Int)` method) -- thus you are loosing type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to check if the list is not null, or the maxBy method will fail

```scala
val myList: List[Foo] = List();

val unsafeMax = myList.maxBy(_.propertyBar).propertyBar
// java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max

val safeMax = if (myList.isEmpty) 0 else myList.maxBy(_.propertyBar).propertyBar;
safeMax == 0
```